# How to cut string before and after comma PHP

Tags: php

```
$MyValue = "1111,5555";
```

I want result this.

```
$Value_1 = "1111";
$Value_2 = "5555";
```

Please help me.

Comment: How about `explode()`?

Comment: Please try rephrase your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**explode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$MyValue = '1111,5555';

$MyValue = explode(',', $MyValue);

echo $MyValue[0]; //1111
echo $MyValue[1]; //5555
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/7hf2vSD5)